# WooCommerce Hide Add To Cart Button on Loop & Product Page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm working on a woocommerce theme and I'm required to hide the add to cart button for products that have 0 as price, as these products may only be inquired and not added to cart. I have successfully hidden the 'add to cart' button on the product page however, I am having a hard time doing so on the shop page/category page.

Below is my code for filtering the add to cart as well as changing the default 'Free!' message.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_free_price_html',  'hide_free_price_notice' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_free_price_html',           'hide_free_price_notice' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price_notice' );


/**
* Changes woocommerce default 'Free!' to return message
*/
function hide_free_price_notice( $price ) {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 30 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );



  return 'Please inquire for pricing';
```

}

I have also tried filtering all add to cart buttons on loop, however this did not work either.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
```

}

Any suggestions? I'm looking to see if I can hide it with CSS...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to change the 'Free!' message to 'POA' and also hide the cart. 
Note: There seems to be an issue with this on WooCommerce version V2.1?

```
 * Swop the 'Free!' price notice and hide the cart with 'POA' in WooCommerce
 */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_free_price_html',  'hide_free_price_notice' ); 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_free_price_html',           'hide_free_price_notice' ); 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price_notice' );

function hide_free_price_notice( $price ) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    return 'POA';   
}
```